# How to access puppet hash name in templates

Tags: puppet

I've defined a hash like so in my nodes.pp:

```
net::addr { "eth5":
        rt => {
                rt1 => {
                        address => '192.168.10.0',
                        netmask => '255.255.255.0',
                        gateway => '192.5.28.19',
                        src     => '192.5.28.21'
                },
        }
```

What I can't get to access is the title of the hash in my templates, so I want to print out the title of the hash i.e. "eth5", how can I do that? Also I have a variable called $int in my define class in the file for my module (/etc/puppet/modules/net/addr.pp), how can I access that using the scope.lookupvar function from this template in the same module?

Thanks
Dan

Comment: In the case of that example, the `eth5` is the title of the resource being defined, not related to the hash variable being used as a parameter to the resource - can you clarify how this this fits in with the defined type you're using?

Comment: Hi Shane, I'm using the following in my class: define addr::net ($route={},){$int = $name file { "routes-${name}": ensure => 'present', mode => '0655', owner => 'root', group => 'root', path=> "/opt/routes/route-${name}", content => template('net/routes-temp.erb'),}. In my templates file I can't don't know how to access this $int or $name variable from my templates alternatively how would I access the title from my template? Thanks Dan

Answer (score 0):

The variables set in the defined type are available as local scope variables to the contents of a template.

Simply using `<%= title %>` or `<%= int %>` in the template should be using the variable that was set for that specific instance of the defined type.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you should be using the namevar, `$name`.

For example, if you define a resource like this:

```
objecttype { "namevar": parameter=>"value" }
```

Then the variables will be set thusly:

```
$name = "namevar"
$parameter = "value"
```

Within templates called from the define, these can be simply referred to a `$name` and `$parameter` (but watch out for reserved words!).